# Yii required validation based on condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

I want to validate field based on condition in Yii model.

I've two fields in my view

*type (radiobutton): standard & special*

*term (textfield) : any text data*

Current I am showing term textbox based on type condition i.e. if type is special then show o/w hide.

I want to validate it using Yii required rule that is if user select radio button special then he must have to fill term textfield data o/w its not mandatory.

If I use required for special then its validating in case of type = standard which is wrong. I've did following custom validation but its not working.

```
public function rules() {
     array('type', 'required'),
     array('term', 'checkTerm', 'trigger' => 'type'),
}

public function checkTerm($attribute, $params) {        
     if ($this->$params['trigger'] == "Special") {
        if (empty($attribute))
           $this->addError($attribute, 'Special term cannot be blank.');
     }
}
```

Where I am going wrong? Need Help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
public function rules() {
     array('type', 'required'),
     array('term', 'checkTerm'),
}

public function checkTerm() {        
     if ($this->type == "Special") {
        if (empty($this->term))
           $this->addError("term", 'Special term cannot be blank.');
     }
}
```

Comment: Its working but validation message not display below to term text field. Also asterisk symbol(*) not showing with label.

Comment: check the update, I think this will solve showing error text issue, but honestly I don't have any idea about the asterisk symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
 if (empty($attribute))
       $this->addError($attribute, 'Special term cannot be blank.');
 }
```

use

```
 if (empty($this->term))
       $this->addError($attribute, 'Special term cannot be blank.');
 }
```